# No puedo lograr que los datos de una base de datos MYSQL se muestren en unas tablas creadas con ttk.treeview en python

Tags: mysql, python, tkinter

estoy teniendo un problema con un programa de gestión de productos que estoy haciendo.
En la sección para que me busque los productos o me muestre la planilla completa no logro hacer que me lo muestre en las tablas que hice con `ttk.treeview`, si lo hago con listas si me deja pero necesito algo mas estético por eso quiero utilizar las tablas, si alguno me puede explicar bien como hacerlo se lo agradecería.
No se como si hacerlo con el `for` como hice con las listas o como, intente con `from PyQt4 import QtGui` (estoy trabajando desde *jupyter notebook*) pero luego de instalarlo no me deja importarlo. Pensé tal vez que hay algo que desconozco que puedo utilizar para simplificar todo jaja es que soy bastante nuevo en esto.

Acá dejo la parte del código para que se ubiquen.

```
def ver():
    ventana_a = tk.Toplevel()
    ventana_a.geometry("1024x768")
    ver = tk.Label(ventana_a, text="PLANILLA DE ENTRADA")
    ver.place (x=424, y=20)

    #Creando Tablas Para mostrar los datos
    def buscar():

        #Tabla de Planillas
        tabla = ttk.Treeview(ventana_a, height = 10, columns = 8)
        tabla["columns"]=("#0","#1","#2","#3","#4","#5","#6","#7")
        tabla.column("#0", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
        tabla.column("#1", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
        tabla.column("#2", width=130, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
        tabla.column("#3", width=130, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
        tabla.column("#4", width=130, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
        tabla.column("#5", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
        tabla.column("#6", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
        tabla.column("#7", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
        tabla.heading('#0', text = 'ID', anchor =CENTER)
        tabla.heading('#1', text = 'Fecha', anchor = CENTER)
        tabla.heading('#2', text = 'Codigo', anchor = CENTER)
        tabla.heading('#3', text = 'Marca', anchor = CENTER)
        tabla.heading('#4', text = 'Producto', anchor = CENTER)
        tabla.heading('#5', text = 'Cantidad', anchor = CENTER)
        tabla.heading('#6', text = 'Tamaño', anchor = CENTER)
        tabla.heading('#7', text = 'Precio', anchor = CENTER)
        tabla.pack()
        tabla.place(x=10, y=100)

        """listaF=tk.Listbox(ventana_a, width=15, height=10)
        listaF.pack()
        listaF.place(x=10, y=100)

        listaC=tk.Listbox(ventana_a, width=10, height=10)
        listaC.pack()
        listaC.place(x=75, y=100)

        listaM=tk.Listbox(ventana_a, width=10, height=10)
        listaM.pack()
        listaM.place(x=135, y=100)

        listaP=tk.Listbox(ventana_a, width=30, height=10)
        listaP.pack()
        listaP.place(x=195, y=100)

        listaCA=tk.Listbox(ventana_a, width=10, height=10)
        listaCA.pack()
        listaCA.place(x=355, y=100)

        listaT=tk.Listbox(ventana_a, width=20, height=10)
        listaT.pack()
        listaT.place(x=415, y=100)

        listaPRE=tk.Listbox(ventana_a, width=20, height=10)
        listaPRE.pack()
        listaPRE.place(x=475, y=100)"""

            #Conectar a la Base de Datos
        db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="inventario")

        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM Entrada_Transporte")

        """for row in c:
            listaF.insert(0,row[1])
            listaC.insert(0,row[2])
            listaM.insert(0,row[3])
            listaP.insert(0,row[4])
            listaCA.insert(0,row[5])
            listaT.insert(0,row[6])
            listaPRE.insert(0,row[7])"""

        db.commit()

        c.close()

    """def dbuscar_c():
        db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="inventario")

        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT Codigo FROM Entrada_Transporte WHERE Codigo='%s'")

        db.commit()

        c.close()"""           

    #Boton para Mostrar Todo
    bttodo = tk.Button(ventana_a, text="Mostrar Planilla Completa", command = buscar)
    bttodo.pack()
    bttodo.place(x=110, y=500)

    #Buscador por filtros
    #Variable Buscador por Codigo
    """buscar_c = tk.StringVar()
    buscar_ctx = tk.Entry(ventana_a, textvariable=buscar_c)
    buscar_ctx.place(x=10, y=400, width=110, height=30)
    btbuscar_c = tk.Button(ventana_a, text = "Buscar por Codigo", command = dbuscar_c)
    btbuscar_c.pack()
    btbuscar_c.place(x=10, y=380)"""

    #Boton para Regresar al menu
    atras = tk.Button(ventana_a, text="Atras", command=ventana_a.destroy)
    atras.pack()
    atras.place(x=10, y=500)

#Boton para Mostrar            
btmostrar = tk.Button(ventana_a, text="Ver Planilla", command = ver)
btmostrar.pack()
btmostrar.place(x=210, y=500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo cambiando todo por este esquema, usando orientado a objetos.

```
`#---Definimos la funcion para abrir "ENTRADAS (PLANILLAS)"---

class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title="", headers=[], height=20, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._title = tk.Label(self, text=title, background="#F7F2E0",height=2, pady=5)
        self._headers = headers
        self._tree = ttk.Treeview(self,
                                 height=height,
                                 columns=self._headers, 
                                 show="headings")
        self._title.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="x")

    # Agregamos dos scrollbars 
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self._tree.yview)
    vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self._tree.xview)
    hsb.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

    self._tree.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    self._tree.pack(side="left")

    for header in self._headers:
        self._tree.heading(header, text=header.title())
        self._tree.column(header, stretch=True,
                          width=tkFont.Font().measure(header.title()))

def add_row(self, row):
    self._tree.insert('', 'end', values=row)
    for i, item in enumerate(row):
        col_width = tkFont.Font().measure(item)
        if self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=None) < col_width:
                self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=col_width)


def consulta():

   conn = pymysql.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="root",
   passwd="",
   database="DBDistribuidora")
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT Fecha, Codigo, Nombre, Marca, Cantidad, Precio FROM entrada_consignacion")
   return cursor
   conn.close()


def entrada_reporte():

    t3 = tk.Toplevel()#ventana principal
    t3.title("INVENTARIO")
    t3.geometry('530x650')
    t3.resizable(False,False)
    t3.focus_set()
    t3.grab_set()

clientes_headers = ("Fecha", "Codigo", "Nombre","Marca","Cantidad","Precio")
clientes_tab = Table(t3, title="ENTRADAS DE MERCADERIAS", headers=clientes_headers)
clientes_tab.pack()

cursor = consulta()#aquí trae el resultado de la consulta a la BD

#Aquí carga la tabla
for row in cursor:
    clientes_tab.add_row(row)`
```